# Creating pivot table with macro - subscript out of range

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create pivot table macro. For this, I have input data and I have a recorded macro on it. However, I am getting an error since I want to use it in multiple areas of the code.

Here is some sample data:

[image]

I need output like this:

[image]

```
Sub macro5()
'
' macro5 Macro
'

'
    Range("A2:C16").Select
    Range("C16").Activate
    Sheets.Add
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet2").PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotCache. _
        CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="Sheet6!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable5" _
        , DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion12
    Sheets("Sheet6").Select
    Cells(3, 1).Select
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable5").PivotFields("Item")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable5").PivotFields("Category")
        .Orientation = xlColumnField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable5").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable5").PivotFields("Price"), "Sum of Price", xlSum
End Sub
```

I am getting an error at the highlighted part.

Can anyone help me figure out why?

Comment: Which part is highlighted? Exactly what error are you getting?

Comment: Sorry its not showing up here...activeWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet2").PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotCache. _
        CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="Sheet6!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable5" _
        , DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion12

Answer (score 1):

Your code only works if there is already an existing pivot table from the same dataset on Sheet2, called PivotTable3. Pivot tables share a PivotCache, and if one exists, Excel won't create another, but reuse the existing. That is what your macro is trying to do.

I suggest recording a macro with no pivot table in your document. That way the pivot-cache-creating-code will appear in the recorded macro. If you need multiple pivot tables, then you can use the above macro for the next pivot tables, but make sure to point to your first pivot table's cache.

**What you must consider when recording a macro to insert pivot tables:**

Notice that the macro recorder recorded some fixed names (e.g. sheet names, pivot table names, data input area). Make sure these are correct, and if not, make them dynamic with variables or otherwise.

Here is a sample code for creating a new pivot table:

```
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    "Sheet2!R1C1:R9C3", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15).CreatePivotTable _
    TableDestination:="Sheet3!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion15
```

Notice how it is different form yours.

*Now about the problematic parts:*

```
SourceData:="Sheet2!R1C1:R9C3"
```

If you want your source data to be dynamic, change this. E.g. to make it use your current selection, use this:

```
SourceData:=Selection
```

Another interesting part:

```
TableDestination:="Sheet3!R3C1"
```

If you just use empty string (""), it will always insert the pivot table on a new sheet (which will also be activated immediately):

```
TableDestination:=""
```

The name of the pivot table is not a problem, as from Excel 2007 and up, you can have multiple pivot tables with the same name, as long as they are on different sheets. If you want more pivot tables on the same sheet, you will have to mind the TableName property too.

OK, I could go on about this for many pages. I hope this helps! If you have questions, do ask.